# Simple application using titanium android

Tags: android, titanium

I am new in android and working on titanium platform but not getting how & where to write the code for it.I want step by step procedure for 'hello world' application in titanium android  and not getting much help from web also.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the quick start:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Quick+Start

This has an example of the hello world app that comes when you create a project. At the bottom of this page is a link to the example application "Kitchen sink" which has an example of just about everything titanium does. Also there is a link to the API.

A quick upskilling that might point you on the right direction is that a titanium project has a resources folder, inside the resources folder by default is an "app.js" file, this is the starting point of every app. You write your first page here / install db etc. and then link to other files from there. Everything goes into the resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Appcelerator's own [training resources](http://training.appcelerator.com) for getting started with Titanium.